# Checking validity other than Truth Table.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

In this particular sequent:

**q ⊢(p∧q)∨(¬p∧q)**

which is invalid (I drew a Truth Table, since it wasn't self-evident to me); the following explanation has been given:

> **The premise is q. By (tnd) we get p ∨ ¬p. We know start an assumption based proof based on the latter. Assume: p In this case by
>   (∧i) we get p ∧ q. Assume: ¬p In this case by (∧i) we get ¬p ∧ q. Thus
>   ¬p ∧ q holds only on the premise q.**

I understand the need for a contradiction based assumption proof, however, I am having trouble connecting the last sentence in the explanation to proving invalidity. I actually had to draw a truth-table to see that this sequent was invalid.

My question is: how do I figure during writing my proof (the way it is formally done) that the sequent I am trying to proof is actually not valid? I continue to apply rules and things usually work out if the formulae are valid, but I can't seem to be able to tell during a proof that it is invalid.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean with the sequent being invalid?

Answer (score 1):

The end confuses me as well. 
I'd say you first show by [Conjunction Introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_introduction)
$$q,p\vdash p\land q$$
and from this by [Disjunction Introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_introduction)
$$q,p\vdash (p\land q)\lor (\neg p\land q)$$
and from this by [Deduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deduction_theorem)
$$\tag1q\vdash p\to ((p\land q)\lor (\neg p\land q)).$$
The same way, we show
$$\tag2q\vdash \neg p\to ((p\land q)\lor (\neg p\land q)).$$
It seems you accept Tertium Non Datur
$$\tag3\vdash p\lor \neg p, $$
so that we obtain by [Disjunction Elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_elimination) from $(1)$, $(2)$, $(3)$
$$ q\vdash (p\land q)\lor (\neg p\land q).$$

Comment: My apologies, I actually made a mistake in my Truth Table, which is why I thought that the sequent was invalid. I took the mistake further by thinking the explanation was actually a proof for invalidity, and got confused because I did my own proof exactly like you wrote. Thank you.